# How to move divs on button clicks with jquery (or javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to create a navigation system that "pushes" one fullscreen div out of view and one into view when clicking a button. My code has two problems:

1. It only works once. After clicking a button it wont do the action again unless the page is reloaded.
2. The second problem is that if one selects: page 2 first -> home -> page 1. Then page 1 goes in as an overlay instead of "pushing" home to the left.

Does any one know how to solve one or both of the problems, or have a better solution to achive the same effect?

Codepen with the current code: http://codepen.io/a_ij/pen/XpZmvz

Code:

```css
/* CSS */

html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#home {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    z-index: 9;
    display: block;
    background-color: #1abc9c;
}

#page1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 100vw;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    z-index: 99;
    background-color: #2ecc71;
}

#page2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100vh;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    background-color: #3498db;
}

.moveleft {
     transform:translate(-100vw, 0);
     -moz-transform:translate(-100vw, 0);
     -ms-transform:translate(-100vw, 0);
     -webkit-transform:translate(-100vw, 0);
     -o-transform:translate(-100vw, 0);
     transition: transform 700ms;
     -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
     transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.86,.01,.77,.78);
     -webkit-transition-delay: 200ms;
     transition-delay: 200ms;
}

.movecenter {
     transform: translate(0, 0);
     -moz-transform: translate(0, 0);
     -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
     -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
     -o-transform: translate(0, 0);
     transition: transform 700ms;
     -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
     transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.86,.01,.77,.78);
     -webkit-transition-delay: 200ms;
     transition-delay: 200ms;
}

.moveup {
    transform: translate(0, -100vh);
    -moz-transform: translate(0, -100vh);
    -ms-transform: translate(0, -100vh);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -100vh);
    -o-transform: translate(0, -100vh);
    transition: transform 700ms;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.86,.01,.77,.78);
    -webkit-transition-delay: 200ms;
    transition-delay: 200ms;
}

.movedown {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate(0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate(0, 0);
    transition: transform 700ms;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.86,.01,.77,.78);
    -webkit-transition-delay: 200ms;
    transition-delay: 200ms;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- HTML -->
<div id="home">
  <button id="gop1">Page1</button>
  <button id="gop2">Page2</button>
 </div>
 <div id="page1">Here is one page <button id="goh1">Home</button></div>
<div id="page2">Here is the second page<button id="goh2">Home</button></div>

<!-- Scripts -->

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#gop1').click(function() {
      $('#home, #page1').addClass('moveleft');
      });
  });
</script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#goh1').click(function() {
      $('#home, #page1').addClass('movecenter');
      });
  });
</script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#gop2').click(function() {
      $('#home, #page2').addClass('moveup');
      });
  });
</script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#goh2').click(function() {
      $('#home, #page2').addClass('movedown');
      });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: remove the class before adding it and then wait 1ms with a timeout to add it - the problem is that it won't transition since it still has the same css-class

Comment: without removing class or sliding the divs you can just hide() and show() the divs using jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove class then add it like this..

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#gop1').click(function() {
      $('#home, #page1').removeAttr('class');
  $('#home, #page1').addClass('moveleft');
  });


  $('#goh1').click(function() {
      $('#home, #page1').removeAttr('class');
  $('#home, #page1').addClass('movecenter');
  });



  $('#gop2').click(function() {
      $('#home, #page2').removeAttr('class');
  $('#home, #page2').addClass('moveup');
  });



$('#goh2').click(function() {
    $('#home, #page2').removeAttr('class');
  $('#home, #page2').addClass('movedown');
  });

});
```

> Just Copy and Paste this and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Change your script to this way:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#gop1').click(function() {
       $('#home, #page1').removeClass('movecenter');
            $('#home, #page1').addClass('moveleft');
      });
       $('#goh1').click(function() {
       $('#home, #page1').removeClass('moveleft');
            $('#home, #page1').addClass('movecenter');
      });
       $('#gop2').click(function() {
       $('#home, #page2').removeClass('movedown');
            $('#home, #page2').addClass('moveup');
      });
      $('#goh2').click(function() {
       $('#home, #page2').removeClass('moveup');
            $('#home, #page2').addClass('movedown');
      });
  });
</script>
```

To make it more simple I removed multiple  open and close `script` tags. But that is not the problem. Its just for the simplicity.
 The problem is resolved by adding extra `removeClass` method as shown in code above.

Answer (score 0):

The solution of @Minksmnm works, but removing the attribut class is not a proper way because you may have other classes than the transition classes and you may not want to remove these other classes.

The solutions of @vvtx and @Parvez don't solve the second point.

I advise you to create a function :

```
<script>
    function removeTransitionClasses () {
        $('#home, #page1').removeClass('moveleft');
        $('#home, #page1').removeClass('movecenter');
        $('#home, #page2').removeClass('moveup');
        $('#home, #page2').removeClass('movedown');
    };
</script>
```

and call this function before adding transition classes in all your `click` callbacks.